Bitbucket and SCM access
I am using Maven 3.9 and have a Bitbucket-pipeline for CICD. In my pipeline I execute the following in order to increment and commit the release number.
Pipeline
mvn -B release:prepare

results in a BUILD SUCCESS
Then when the pipeline runs:
mvn -B release:perform -Darguments="-DskipTests -Dmaven.deploy.skip=true -Dmaven.resolver.transport=wagon"

Error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.1.1:prepare (default-cli) on project notification-service: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '104.XXX.XXX.XX' to the list of known hosts.
[ERROR] Unauthorized
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights

pom.xml
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxx/notification-service.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxx/notification-service.git</developerConnection>
    <url>ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxx/notification-service</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

If I run these commands from my localhost, it works as expected, no errors and it commits the new incremented project.version to Git.
I did add a SSH key pair to Bitbucket (Repository Settings -> SSH Keys). I then added the public key to the (Repository Settings -> Access Keys). * It does say:

Use access keys to gain read-only access to this repository

So I am not 100% sure the pipeline is even using this key, but it is read-only anyway so would not allow git commits.
Question
I am obviously doing something wrong with setting up the piplelines access rights. Any guidance appreciated. How do I configure permissions for the pipleline to do the mvn -B release:perform?

This may answer it:  https://www.cloudrepo.io/articles/continuous-integration-a-complete-guide-to-bitbucket-pipelines-with-maven-repositories.html#:~:text=mvn%20release%3Aprepare%20release%3Aperform,key%20associated%20with%20a%20Pipeline
